# How to make an object static in lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm making an android game in LUA with the corona SDK and I want to stack boxes onto each other.

I can add the boxes to physics but when the boxes land I want them to become static so they don't move anymore after they have landed and I have no idea how to do that. Can someone please help me? I already tried it with `physics.removeBody()` after I added them but that didn't work.

I'm sure the solution will be pretty easy but I'm relatively new to the corona SDK.

Answer (score 0):

One way of accomplishing this would be to - after

```
physics.removeBody()
```

add it again, this time as **static**, eg.:

```
physics.addBody(bodyObj, "static", ...)
```

Remember this about [physics.removeBody()](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/physics/removeBody.html) though:

> This call cannot be used in a collision event. However, your collision
>   handler may set a flag or include a time delay via
>   timer.performWithDelay() so that the action can occur in the next
>   application cycle or later